# Error d3-ng2-service in Angular when is run And Build project

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

When I run the project or build it throws an error.
I am using d3-ng2-service

[image]

> ERROR in node_modules/d3-ng2-service/index.d.ts(2,65): error TS2305:
>   Module
>   '"C:/project/myapp-d3/node_modules/d3-ng2-service/src/bundle-d3"' has
>   no exported member 'ThresholdArrayGenerator'.

In addition is a way for skip this error and build project?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { D3Service , D3} from 'd3-ng2-service';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule
],
providers: [D3Service],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.components.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {D3, D3Service} from 'd3-ng2-service';
import * as d3 from 'd3';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  d3: D3;

  constructor(d3service: D3Service) {
    this.d3 = d3service.getD3();
  }
}
```

Run

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrEcX.png)

d3-ng2-service/index.d.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h0Rz.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question.  Images of your code make it harder to help solve your issue

Comment: Related github [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29550).

Comment: I did not get the right answer @Mark

Comment: Completed @kenlukas